# Firebase Recycler Adapter don't show view property when removeValue

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to delete an item in Firebase Recycler Adapter with this code:

```
messageAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();
```

but in Recycle view, the view of this item messed up:
[image]

Here is my code about Firebase Recycler Adapter. It works fine exept when i delete item.
**MessageViewHolder** Class:

```
public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        public TextView tvMessage;
        public TextView tvDateSending;
        public CircleImageView ivMessenger;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;


        public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
            tvDateSending = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateSending);
            ivMessenger = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMessenger);
            linearLayout= (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llOneToOneChat);
            v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

        }
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.add(0,1 , 0, "Edit");
            menu.add(0, COPY, 0, "Copy");
            menu.add(0, DELETE, 0, "Delete");
        }

    }
```

**MessageAdapter** class:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>{

        private Context context;
        private long prevMessageTime=0;
        public int position;

        public int getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public void setPosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        public MessageAdapter(Class<Message> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<MessageViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref, Context context) {
            super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message message, final int position) {
            //do something
            viewHolder.tvMessage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    setPosition(position);
                    return false;
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

In Activity, I override the **onContextItemSelected**

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int position = -1;
        try {
            position = messageAdapter.getPosition();
        } catch (Exception e) {
//            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                // do your stuff

                break;
            case 2:
                // copy message
                if (position!= -1){
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) OneToOneConversationActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    String text = messageAdapter.getItem(position).getMessage();
                    ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", text);
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                }

                break;
            case 3:
                //delete message
                if (position!= -1)
                    messageAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();
                break;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

how to make that view disappears from screen?

Comment: please post your full code.. What you have done while deleting..

Comment: @ArpitPatel I've updated my question. pls help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the trick that can take the deleted view away from RecyclerView:
here is my method:

```
public void deleteMessage(int position){
    MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder= (MessageViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    messageViewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    messageViewHolder.tvDateSending.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

with linearlayout is the view contains all component in this viewHolder!